# Security patch 5344 (Shoplift) Error executing check

Tags: magento-1.7, security, patches

On Magereport.com in my site patches Security patch 5344 (Shoplift) showing Error executing check. how to resolve it ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure this happens when you changed your admin URL or path. magereport checks /admin for such vulnerabilities and thus cannot run the check